# limiting elements,when i click more to load another elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code I tried is

```
jQuery(function($) {
var visible =3;
$('#sc li:gt('+(visible - 1)+')').hide();    
$('#more').click(function() {      
    var Index = $('#sc').children('li:visible:last').index(),
    nextIndex = currentIndex + (visible + 1);
    $('#sc li').hide();        
    $('ul li:lt(' + nextIndex + '):gt(' + Index + ')').show();        
    });    
});
```

I want to limit the elements, but when i clicked more nothing will happen.

Comment: creat a fiddle please

Comment: when i clicked more, it cant load the next elements

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are defining `Index` variable and using `currentIndex` in the next line, which of course throws an error, otherwise your code should work. However, you can cache the elements and use `.slice()` method which improves the efficiency of the code.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var visible = 3,
            $li = $('#sc li');

    // hiding the elements
    $li.slice(visible).hide();

    $('#more').on('click', function () {
        // getting index of the last visible element
        var ci = $li.filter(':visible:last').index();
        // slicing and showing next should-be-visible elements
        $li.hide().slice(++ci, ci+visible).show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xRPQj/

Comment: im fetching data in database,

Comment: @user2779464 Okay, so ...? Does this mean you want to lazy-load the data? What does this have to do with showing/hiding elements?

Comment: when i clicked the more function.it cant load the another elements